# Using Indexes in mysql do not improve query time

Tags: mysql

i have this sql query:

```
SELECT Frage_ID 
FROM Session_Fragen WHERE 
(
    Userantwort1 = 0 
    AND Userantwort2 = 0 
    AND Userantwort3 = 0 
    AND Userantwort4 = 0 
    AND Userantwort5 = 0
) AND Session_ID = 17898 
ORDER BY Sessionfrage_ID ASC LIMIT 1;
```

In the beginning this query run very slow.
I added index to improve the speed.
Bevor using indexes i scanned approx. 500.000 rows ...
After using indexes i reduced the rows to approx. 550 (depends on results)
But the query still takes more than 2 sec. to run.

I hope anybody has any improvementtips for me...

tanks a lot!

---

SQL EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  Session_Fragen  index   Session_Fragen_big_index_2,Session_Fragen_big_inde...   PRIMARY     8   NULL    535     Using where
```

---

SHOW INDEXES:

```
Session_Fragen  0   PRIMARY     1   Sessionfrage_ID     A   626229  NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Frage_ID    1   Frage_ID    A   3479    NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Session_Fragen_big_index_2  1   Userantwort1    A   2   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Session_Fragen_big_index_2  2   Userantwort2    A   3   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Session_Fragen_big_index_2  3   Userantwort3    A   5   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Session_Fragen_big_index_2  4   Userantwort4    A   7   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Session_Fragen_big_index_2  5   Userantwort5    A   9   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Session_Fragen_big_index    1   Session_ID  A   16057   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Session_Fragen_big_index    2   Frage_ID    A   626229  NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Session_Fragen_big_index    3          
Sessionfrage_ID     A   626229  NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Userantwort1    1   Userantwort1    A   2   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Userantwort2    1   Userantwort2    A   2   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Userantwort3    1   Userantwort3    A   2   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Userantwort4    1   Userantwort4    A   2   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Userantwort5    1   Userantwort5    A   2   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Session_ID  1   Session_ID  A   16057   NULL    NULL        BTREE
```

---

TABLE STRUCTURE:

```
Session_Fragen  CREATE TABLE `Session_Fragen` (
 `Sessionfrage_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `User_ID` int(7) NOT NULL,
 `SF_Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `Session_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Frage_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Userantwort1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Userantwort2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Userantwort3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Userantwort4` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Userantwort5` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`Sessionfrage_ID`),
 KEY `Frage_ID` (`Frage_ID`),
 KEY `Session_Fragen_big_index_2`         (`Userantwort1`,`Userantwort2`,`Userantwort3`,`Userantwort4`,`Userantwort5`),
 KEY `Session_Fragen_big_index` (`Session_ID`,`Frage_ID`,`Sessionfrage_ID`),
 KEY `Userantwort1` (`Userantwort1`),
 KEY `Userantwort2` (`Userantwort2`),
 KEY `Userantwort3` (`Userantwort3`),
 KEY `Userantwort4` (`Userantwort4`),
 KEY `Userantwort5` (`Userantwort5`),
 KEY `Session_ID` (`Session_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=862095 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Try using SQL JOIN operator, sometimes set based operations may perform faster than regular WHERE operations

Comment: You should probably be using NULL in your UserantworX columns instead of putting in a dummy 0 value.  You're using "0" to mean "no value" when that is exactly what NULL means.  It will probably also speed up your query because the optimizer handles NULLs better than having to look up zeroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the following index for this query:

```
ALTER TABLE Session_Fragen ADD INDEX sf_sess_fragen_id (
  Session_ID, 
  Userantwort1, 
  Userantwort2,
  Userantwort3,
  Userantwort4,
  Userantwort5,
  Sessionfrage_ID,
  Frage_ID
);
```

My reasons are:

- First add all the columns referenced in equality predicates. Put the `Session_ID` column first because it's most likely to narrow down the search quickly.
- After those columns, add the `Sessionfrage_ID` column for sorting. Once the search has found the rows for the conditions in the `WHERE` clause, the rows are effectively in tied order. The order is determined by the next column of the index, and MySQL's optimizer will use this order instead of having to sort the matching rows.
- Finally, add the `Frage_ID` column from the select-list. This is used neither for searching nor for sorting, but including it in the index creates a *covering index*.

I tested this but without reasonable test data, the optimizer didn't automatically use this new index. If I use an [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html) to coax it to use the new index, I get a much better EXPLAIN report (the index hint may be unnecessary if you run this on your real table).

```
mysql> explain SELECT Frage_ID FROM Session_Fragen use index (sf_sess_fragen_id) 
WHERE  (Userantwort1 = 0 AND Userantwort2 = 0 AND Userantwort3 = 0 
    AND Userantwort4 = 0 AND Userantwort5 = 0 ) 
  AND Session_ID = 17898
ORDER BY Sessionfrage_ID ASC LIMIT 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: Session_Fragen
         type: ref
possible_keys: sf_sess_fragen_id
          key: sf_sess_fragen_id
      key_len: 9
          ref: const,const,const,const,const,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

Good things about this EXPLAIN:

- `rows` is nice and low, because the `Session_ID` narrowed down the search.
- `Using index` indicates an index-only query (i.e. covering index), which means the query doesn't have to read table rows at all.
- We don't see `type: index` (index scan), nor do we see `Using filesort`.

See my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really) for more guidelines on designing indexes.

Comment: thx a lot for your support. i will test all the imrpovements you recommended!